# Iscroll for bootstrap modal works just after a windows resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, iscroll

since overflow: auto and overflow: scroll don't work for android 4 and older versions I tried to use Iscroll.js. I use it for 2 normal div and it works fine. but bootstrap modal has a problem with it. it only gets scrolled after a window resize.

---

I tried many things to solve it:

- give the scroll to different div inside model.
- change positions: fixed to absolute and relative.
- give modal divs height and max-height.

none of the them solve this problem.
so please help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. the code can explain the problem.

'
$(".product-it").click(function(){
            $(this).delay(500).queue(function() {

```
 myScroll.refresh();

 $(this).dequeue();
```

});

```
    });
```

'